# Mapping all entities by convention

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping-by-code

I'm playing  with NH 3.2.0 mapping by code. Since I've a scenario in which I can map everithing by convention I would like to add raw entities to the mapper, and then customize them by a custom `ModelInspector` plus the event generated by the `ModelMapper`. Unfortunately the ModelMapper apparently does not allow me to add entity dirctly, instead he want object implementing `IConformistHoldersProvider`, so I eventually end with pass empty classes implementing  ClassMapping for each entity I want to map. Is there some smartest way to achieve the same ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I found myself, problem was that I was using `mapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities();`
the problem simply does not sussists if I use

```
 mapper.CompileMappingFor()
```

and I pass the required entities...